# Php MySql query by distance and time

Tags: mysql

I have this query that I would like to add a time search to.

Here is my working query:

```
$query = "SELECT *,(((acos(sin((".$lat."*pi()/180)) * sin((Lat*pi()/180)) + 
cos((".$lat."*pi()/180)) * cos((Lat*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$lon."- Lon) * 
pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) as distance 
FROM items 
HAVING distance < ".$distance." 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT ".$min." , ".$max."";
```

I would like to add something like this

```
WHERE timestamp > ".$somePastDate."
```

For hours now I have tried all combinations I can think of with no luck. I bet its simple too and I'll be shaking my head. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what's the problem? `WHERE now() > '2014-01-01'` works just fine...

Comment: Oh sorry, timestamp is a column I named and update myself, not auto updated by mysql

Comment: if it's a msyql date/datetime field, then just its name instead of `now()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a nested query for this, as follows

```
 SELECT *, big_cosine_law_distance_formula AS distance
   FROM (
     SELECT *
       FROM items
      WHERE items.timestamp > ".$somePastDate."
    ) AS i
 HAVING distance < ".$distance."
```

The inner query will narrow down your items by time, so you don't have to grind out the big distance formula on them all.

You might also consider using a faster bounding-box-based search to narrow down your items spatially, as described here.  http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

You can troubleshoot this kind of thing by starting with the inner query.

```
      SELECT *
       FROM items
      WHERE items.timestamp > ".$somePastDate."
```

When you're getting reliable results from that query, add the outer one.

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea of not doing the calculating for everyone. Trying to get it to work now, but no items showing still

Comment: Yeah I was just doing that and I must be having a problem with my time variable even though it echos out correctly. Basically I want to never show and item over 31 days old so itll always be 31 days from current time.

Comment: MySql was having errors over my H:i:s part of the timestamp I make for the past. I removed it and it shows items now but does not limit them actually by date lol

Comment: Yeah that is my problem, the hours min and secs. I cannot get any output with them in the timestamp variable and i get no limiting when its removed. But I really like your answer and will work better than I expected to get, when I finally figure this H:i:s part out

Comment: Even this does not work but still displays all SELECT * FROM items WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 31 DAY)